# How to Add a collection of elements to my array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have a method to add a collection of generic elements to my array but do not know how to implement this. I have symbolised the line of code that I have been having trouble with as `COLLECTION`. I do not know what to write in place of this. My array is a circular ring array.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class CircularArrayRing<E> implements Ring<E> {

    public E[] elements; //array of E

    private int capacity;
    private int writePos  = 0;
    private int available = 0;

    public CircularArrayRing(int size) {   //circular array constructor

        capacity = size;

    }


    public boolean add(E e) {

        if(available < capacity){ 
            if(writePos >= capacity){
                writePos = 0;
            }
            elements[writePos] = e;     //add element e
            writePos++;
            available--;
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {

        if(available < capacity){
            if(writePos >= capacity){
                writePos = 0;
            }
            elements[writePos] = COLLECTION;    //how do add a collection of elements?
            writePos++;
            available++;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterate over the collection, increment the write position for each element and set the element at that position. It's basically the same as `for( E e : c) { add(e); }` - and I'd probably implement it that way. Just keep track if the return values and act if you get `false`, or yet better check `available >= c.size()` before executing the loop.

Comment: Side note: I guess `available++;` is not what you want in `addAll()`.

Comment: Additional side note: what does `available < capacity` mean? I assume you rather mean to initialize `available` to the value of `capacity` and then check for `available > 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about iterating and triggering `add()` one by one?

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c){
  for(E e : c){
    add(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The functional way.

```
c.forEach(this::add);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out some ideas here:

https://github.com/bekkopen/Continuous-Delivery-example/blob/master/webapp/src/main/java/no/bekk/bekkopen/cde/jetty/config/CollectionBuilder.java#L10

```
public static <T> Set<T> newSet(final T... elements) {
    return new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(elements));
}

public static <T> List<T> newList(final T... elements) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(elements));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some examples:

```
public void testCollectionAdd() {
    if (!isAddSupported()) return;

    Object[] elements = getFullElements();
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        resetEmpty();
        boolean r = collection.add(elements[i]);
        confirmed.add(elements[i]);
        verify();
        assertTrue("Empty collection changed after add", r);
        assertTrue("Collection size is 1 after first add",
                   collection.size() == 1);
    }

    resetEmpty();
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        boolean r = collection.add(elements[i]);
        confirmed.add(elements[i]);
        verify();
        if (r) size++;
        assertEquals("Collection size should grow after add",
                     size, collection.size());
        assertTrue("Collection should contain added element",
                   collection.contains(elements[i]));
    }
}
```

Full code here:

http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=WKY7Buaz9RI_B0BqM_HKnkm6lqY&cid=9RkvURzZ1wM&s=How%20to%20Add%20a%20collection%20of%20elements%20to%20my%20array%3F&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&projSelected=false&filterChecked,=true&mp,=1&filterChecked=true&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1#L79